# date and dow in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

how do I get date and day of week together in PHPExcel?

I am able to get date in this format (14 Apr 2011)using

PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15

I want the date in this format "Thu 14 Apr 2011" or "14 Apr 2011 Thu"

Please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Dates in cells are held as an Excel dateserial number, and the date format mask (such as FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15) tells Excel how to display that number as a date.

If you want the cell to display the date in the format like "Thu 14 Apr 2011", you change the format mask, as you would in Excel itself. A mask for that format would look something like:

```
"ddd dd mmm yyyy"
```

If you want to convert this to a PHP date, then you can use

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()
```

or

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()
```

to convert the Excel dateserial value to a PHP date/timestamp value, or a PHP DateTime Object, and then use

```
date()
```

or

```
DateTime::format()
```

to convert to a displayable format

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just to convert it from PHP code?

```
  $your_date = '14 Apr 2011';

  $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('j M Y', $your_date);
  $new_date = $dt->format('D d M Y');

  echo $new_date;
```

Output

> Thu 14 Apr 2011

Or change format to `'d M Y D'` to get output as `'14 Apr 2011 Thu'`.

For more about how to format your output check [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).